# preg_split by space and tab outside quotes

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I am trying to get `preg_split()` to split the following 2 strings, by space/tab (needs to work on both).

```
autodiscover.microsoft.com. 3600 IN A   131.107.125.5
```

and

```
microsoft.com.      3600    IN  TXT "v=spf1 include:_spf-a.microsoft.com include:_spf-b.microsoft.com include:_spf-c.microsoft.com -all"
```

The trick is that in the second instance the last part with quotes, should not be split.

From looking on the StackOverflow, I have found that I probably need to use this.

```
$results = preg_split("/'[^']*'(*SKIP)(*F)|\x20/", $str);
```

Sadly I cannot get it to work.
I have tried several things like this for instance, but nothing works.

```
"\s+"(*SKIP)(*F)|\x20
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just split your input according to the below regex. `\h+` matches one or more horizontal space characters ie, spaces , tabs.

```
(?:'[^']*'|"[^"]*")(*SKIP)(*F)|\h+
```

`(?:'[^']*'|"[^"]*")` matches all the single and double quotes strings. `(*SKIP)(*F)` causes the match to fail and picks up all the characters which are matched by the pattern  present just after to `|`. In our case, it's `\h+` which matches one or more horizontal spaces.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cL1pT8/3)

```
$str = 'microsoft.com.      3600    IN  TXT "v=spf1 include:_spf-a.microsoft.com include:_spf-b.microsoft.com include:_spf-c.microsoft.com -all"';
$match =  preg_split('~(?:\'[^\']*\'|"[^"]*")(*SKIP)(*F)|\h+~', $str);
print_r($match);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => microsoft.com.
    [1] => 3600
    [2] => IN
    [3] => TXT
    [4] => "v=spf1 include:_spf-a.microsoft.com include:_spf-b.microsoft.com include:_spf-c.microsoft.com -all"
)
```

Comment: I prefer `(['"])[^'"]*\1(*SKIP)(*F)|\h+`

Comment: Wow, I never knew about `*SKIP` and `*F`.